# Mocking NSDateFormatter for Tests

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

Is there any way to mock the current `Date` of the `DateFormatter`?

I have the following code, and I wanted to be able to control the current date to allow me to control the result. I had the idea of overriding `.string(from: )` and control it that way, but not sure if this is the best approach.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short

let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: dateToConvert)
```

Edit 1: `doesRelativeDateFormatting` will make the result be `today` if the current device date is the same day as the date that I want to format. What I want to know is if it is possible to change the current Device `Date` used by `DateFormatter`.

Edit 2:
Day 1: `Device Date` is 4/11/2020 and `dateToConvert` is 4/11/2020 as such `dateString = Today`
Day 2: If I run the test again the next day the `Device Date` is 5/11/2020 and `dateToConvert` will still be 4/11/2020 and because fo that `dateString = Yesterday`

My problem is that the result will keep on changing. My two options so far are to change the Mocked API responses based on the current date or change the `DateFormatter`

Comment: What do you mean with the _current_ Date? Not `Date()`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson added more information, hope this time it is more clear

Comment: The DateFormatter will use the date given to it in `string(from:)` and not the device date so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I added an example of my problem. I am using iOSSnapshotTestCase to test the UI by comparing images, but the dates on the UI keep on changing because the device date will keep on changing and relative will never be the same.

Comment: I have never used iOSSnapshotTestCase and I still don't really understand what it is you are trying to test and what you are asking about so I leave it to someone else to help you.

Answer (score 0):

DateFormatter is a subclass of Formatter which is an open class, so you can create a class called `DateFormatterMock` which inherits from `Formatter`.

So in your code you use the variables with the Formatter type so you can call the methods, (in your case, string(from:)). The last change is to allow inject it, the simpler way using the intializer.

Example

```
class DateFormatterMock: Formatter {
    var returnedStringValue: String?
    override func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {
        return returnedStringValue
    }
}

protocol MyFactoryProtocol {
    func getString(date: Date) -> String
}

class MyFactory: MyFactoryProtocol {
    private let formatter: Formatter

    init(formatter: Formatter) {
        self.formatter = formatter
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(formatter: DateFormatter())
    }

    func getString(date: Date) -> String {
        formatter.string(for: date) ?? ""
    }
}

let dateFormatterMock = DateFormatterMock()
dateFormatterMock.returnedStringValue = "^_^"
let sut = MyFactory(formatter: dateFormatterMock)

print(sut.getString(date: Date()))
```

Anyway, I believe that your component should receive the info to be displayed from outside. The logic to create the date format should not be part of the small UI component for which has sense to do the snapshop test.

This kind of tests are very difficult to keep for a whole screen.